# How to initialize and access variables from karate-config.js?

Tags: javascript, config, karate

I am new to karate. Trying to figure out 1 thing.
We use same headers in most of the tests. In order to reduce redundancy, I need to include this header in karate-config.js --> So I can straightly access this header in all feature classes.
Ex:

config.appHeader = '{Req-Id : appId}' --> Let's say this is a required header. But appId is being randomly generated. I have another function() in the same config file that generates this appId.

How do I initialize config.appHeader? Should it be '{Req-Id: #appId}'? Please help if you can

Answer (score 0):

You can read JS functions and *invoke* them within `karate-config.js`.

```
var appIdGenerator = read('classpath:my-function.js');
config.appHeader = { 'Req-Id': appIdGenerator() };
```

Sounds like you are new to JS as well, so please take the help of someone who knows JS as well.

And please read this part of the documentation and the examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate#http-header-manipulation